# Symfony 3 : password validation

Tags: symfony, bcrypt

I use this code to validate user password :

```
$encoderService = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
$match = $encoderService->isPasswordValid($user, $request->query->get('password'));
```

but it always returns 'false' even the password is correct

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the password by GET?

Comment: yes i verify the get

Comment: Can you post the entire controller code and the HTML of the form?
Also keep in mind that is a good practice to use the POST method to send sensitive information like passwords.

Comment: $.ajax({
                    url:'{{ (path('setting_acces')) }}',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:{

                        'password':$('#confirmpassword').val()
                    })};

Comment: $encoderService = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $match = $encoderService->isPasswordValid($user, $request->query->get('password'));

Comment: i think the problem is n the isPasswordValid function ! by i cannot find the issue

Comment: When asked to post additional code you should update the question using the edit button underneath it.  Comment code does not format well.  Verify which class security.password_encorder returns.  There are actually two encorder interfaces.  A plain one and a user one.  It is possible that you are not getting a UserPasswordEncorderInterface implementation.  Though I'm guessing the problem is someplace else.

Comment: it returns UserPasswordEncoder

Answer (score 0):

You're using the password encoder in the wrong way... Check [Symfony doc on security](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html)
Here is an example on how to use it.

<kbd>**app/config/security.yml**</kbd>

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Security:
            algorithm: bcrypt
```

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php**</kbd>

```
class SecurityController extends Controller {
    private $tokenManager;
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(CsrfTokenManagerInterface $tokenManager=null, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder) {
        $this->tokenManager=$tokenManager;
        $this->encoder=$encoder;
    }

    **[...]**

    public function editAction(Security $user) {
        if($user->getOldPassword() !== null && $user->getPlainPassword() !== null && $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $user->getOldPassword())) {
            $user->setPassword($this->encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword()));
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>**Form view**</kbd>

```
<form action="{{ form.vars.action }}" method="{{ form.vars.method }}" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); ajaxSubmit($(this));">
    <div class="form-section-title">Change password</div>
    <div class="form-col-2">
        <div class="input-field">
            {{ form_label(form.oldPassword, 'Current password') }}
            {{ form_widget(form.oldPassword, { 'attr': {'autocomplete': 'off' }}) }}
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-col-2">
        <div class="input-field">
            {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first, 'New password') }}
            {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'autocomplete': 'off' }}) }}
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
            {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second, 'Repeat new password) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, { 'attr': {'autocomplete': 'off' }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="{{ form._token.vars.full_name }}" type="hidden" value="{{ form._token.vars.value }}">
    <div class="input-field submit-container">
        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-2 close_action">Annuler</button>
        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-1" type="submit">Valider</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

<kbd>**Javascript submit function**</kbd>

```
function ajaxSubmit(node) {
    $.ajax({
        type: node.attr("method"),
        url: node.attr("action"),
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: new FormData(node[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
    }).done(function(response, status, xhr) {
        //Your code here
    }).fail(function(request, status, error) {
        console.error(request);
        console.error(status);
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Side note: Should be obvious, but you should use `POST` and not `GET` with your AJAX query.

First because `GET` parameters are as clear as day... It's quite dangerous for a password to be changed like that.

Second because, as soon as your site will be in HTTPS, your `POST` parameters will be encrypted. Making it really hard to read the content for anyone sniffing around.

And last, avoid to post code in comments, edit your question instead... ;)